# SVG image falling back to Times New Roman when viewed on a mobile device?

Tags: css, svg, fonts, responsiveness

I have an SVG image on my [website](https://davidpicarazzi.com/aleksa-app/) (I do not have an SSL certificate yet so it may display a security error before you enter) and the font I had used when making this image was Segoe UI. On my desktop it looks fine however whenever I look at it on a mobile device it shows up as Times New Roman. I have tried this as a work around but still no good:

@media (max-width: 576px) {

```
 #heroimg {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 }
```

}

My thought process when adding this code in my css would be that incase whatever device can't load the font, load Arial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert all the text to outlines before uploading the SVG.

You can do this in Adobe Illustrator by selecting the text and going to **Type > Create Outlines**

Comment: Is there a way to do this in adobe xd? That's where I had made the image.

Comment: I'm not sure, the last answer in this thread may be helpful: https://adobexd.uservoice.com/forums/353007-adobe-xd-feature-requests/suggestions/13617501-convert-text-to-outline-so-u-can-use-it-as-blured